# Hiding an activity and keeping its data

Tags: android

I have 2 activities, Activity1 and Activity2:
Both have data.
How can I Hide Activity2 and get back to Activity1 with having both activities data there?

Comment: Create a singleton scoped LiveData, and subscribe to that in both of your Activities. This LiveData should be updated by writes to an SQLite DB underneath.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  If Activity 1 launches Activity 2, you can go to Activity1 again by calling finish and ending Activity 2.  If you launch Activity 2 again, it will be a new instance of the Activity.  It's up to you to provide enough information to Activity 2 to recreate any state you wanted to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here.

Your best option is to use SaveInstanceState and then parse it back out of the intent bundle in the onCreate if exists. This is the proper way to maintain passing your data.

Another option is to maintain a SQLite DB with the data you need to persist.

Another option would be to have a singleton object holding the values you don't want to lose.

(I highly discourage this option)
Another option is to continue stacking, Activity 1 launches Activity 2, which launches activity 1, which launches activity 2, make sure you have single instance listed of them, and you may get lucky and get the same instance back if garbage collection has not occurred.

There are many ways to retain your information. You just need to think through your architecture and what is best for your situation and do the most appropriate action.

If you have a more specific question, I'm happy to give architectural advice, but your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Just using a singleton is not enough, you must expect the data to be possibly null in both cases and be able to reload it even after the process is recreated, so it must also be serialized to disk or bundle

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce panda, unless you work with Ali, why would you say my answer is not enough? I gave him several options for an extremely vague question. You can't say what is enough or not enough with a question of "retain data from activity 1 and 2" lol. That's like diagnosing an engine problem, because I said my car has an issue. You need more info, or you give possible solutions "net casting style" He never said persist between sessions.

Comment: I'm saying that because singletons die. Every android app must consider the ability to persist between  sessions, otherwise process death will cause crashes

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce, the question never mentioned persistent data between sessions. Singleton will stay alive for the session. He asked for the content of Activity 1 and 2 to stay with their content, This could be anything from user filled in text fields to a selected radio button. If someone asks how to get to another house, you don't immediately say "take a plane" you say, well you can walk, drive, bike, or fly, depending on the distance". You are jumping straight to plane lol, but he never asked for it ;). That was my only point.

Comment: I'm saying that it stays alive for the session, but if you can only set the data in Activity 1; then if Activity 2 "expects it to be there", then low memory condition will restart the app in Activity 2. Anyways, it's just a word of caution - this is why the `intent` or `args bundle` remembers this kind of thing

Comment: fair enough ;). I am just trying to answer the specific question without assumptions of low memory or persisting between apps. You took the time to mention that my answer would not be enough, which was not a fair statement as he never mentioned issues of memory or persisting. His question was very vague, so before you knock on other people's answer, please read the question thoroughly and then ask yourself, if the answer provided met the question the way it sits, not the way you imagine it @EpicPandaForce, otherwise it seems you are just stirring a pot for no reason.